# How to solve JFrog config read error when building docker image - [Error] open /root/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf: read-only file system

Tags: docker, artifactory

I'm building a docker image and getting the error:

```
 => ERROR [14/36] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=jfrog-cfg,target=/root/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf     jfrog rt dl --flat artifact  0.7s
------                                                                                                                       
 > [14/36] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=jfrog-cfg,target=/root/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf     jfrog rt dl --flat artifact/artifact.tar.gz;     set -eux;     mkdir -p /usr/local/artifact;     tar xzf artifact.tar.gz -C /usr/local/;     ln -s /usr/local/artifact /usr/local/artifact;:
#22 0.524 [Error] open /root/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf: read-only file system
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/bash -eo pipefail -c jfrog rt dl --flat artifact/${ART_TAG}.tar.gz;     set -eux;     mkdir -p /usr/local/${ART_TAG};     tar xzf ${ART_TAG}.tar.gz -C /usr/local/;     ln -s /usr/local/${ART_VERSION} /usr/local/artifact;]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

The command I use to build the docker image is
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t imagename . --secret id=jfrog-cfg,src=${HOME}/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf` (jfrog config exists at `${HOME}/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf`)

JFrog is working and the artifact I'm downloading exists as I can manually download it outside of using docker.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, docker is run using the `root` user, so `${HOME}` is `/root` and not `/home/your-user-name` or whatever your usual home folder is. Try using explicit full pathnames instead of the env var.

Comment: This isn't the case in my case. I tested with a dummy file in ${HOME} (created as user in my actual home directory) and it was found.